# Magento always loading on https

Tags: url-rewrite, https

Our Magento store is loading on https, not only on the checkout as we wanted.
I set unsecure to http://www.yourdomain.com/ and secure to https://www.yourdomain.com/

Also set the use secure URL's on frontend to yes.

.htaccess does not contain any rewrite rule, we use the default Magento .htaccess.

Does anyone know where this rewrite rule is taking place?

Comment: Have you set them to `http://` and `https://` or `http://www.yourdomain.com/` and `https://www.yourdomain.com/`? Have you looked what is in the database? Have you deleted cache, cookies, sessions, disabled compiler and tried other browsers?

Comment: No I did indeed  set it to: http://www.yourdomain.com/ and https://www.yourdomain.com/. Database contains the same data. Deleted all cache cookies, sessies etc. Can it be set in some Magento file?

Comment: This could also be caused by an extension. Sometimes `<secure_url>` is used in extensions `config.xml` files to force the extension to use a secure connection. Have you tried disabling all extensions?

Comment: Did you check all configuration scopes or just default?

Comment: You can check `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php` -> `public function getSecure`. Also you can search in files for `secure_is_forced`. And also you can view `phpinfo()` through `http://` and check if is set `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` (it shouldn't be) and to check what is the value for `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` (it should be 80, not 443).

Comment: For everyones awareness, his last deleted comment was "This ended up being an extension issue". So this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use Secure URLs in Frontend]Please check in your magento admin System -> Configuration -> General -> Web for "Use Secure URLs in Frontend". If it is yes then revert to no and https will not be used as default and it it will work only on checkout pages

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the following in your admin control panel

System-> Config -> Web -> Unsecure

Most likely you have it set to https://www.domain.com/ it should be http://www.domain.com/

Answer (score 0):

Debug steps:

1. As Brent says and verify the correct configuration scope.
2. You haven't cleared your configuration and block_html cache since the change of 1).
3. Redirect to base URL is set to "off". You or your predecessor have implemented [Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). In this case everything in Magento is configured correctly, but your browser silently rewrites locally to https and requests it as such.

Pretty much what I've seen in the wild.